# django DRF permission_classes = isAuthenticated not working as intended

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using drf 3.14.0 and simple_jwt for my logging.
The authentication seems to work well when i enter a valid token, but permission classes doesn't stop a an AnonymousUser from acceding my view.

**settings**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'users.authentification.CustomJWTAuth',
    )
}
```

**view**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
        print(request.user.is_authenticated, file=sys.stderr)
        u_serializer = GetUserSerializer(request.user)
        user_data = JSONRenderer().render(u_serializer.data)
        return Response(user_data, 200)
```

When i do an api call without a valid user and the following view
the call enters list and prints me false on request.user.is_authenticated, which shouldn't be possible I believe.

I welcome any ideas

Comment: Explicitly check authentication in the view : `if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return Response({"message": "Unauthorized"}, status=401)
`

Comment: It's weird that I have to do that, as normaly IsAuthenticated does the same, but it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `permission_classes` from method to ViewSet class:

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def list(self, request):
        ...
```